# Adding new fields to large MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I help run a quite large ecomm website as we are running into issues adding fields to InnoDB tables due to the size of our data.

Its not even "that" big... looking at around 385,000 rows, 500mb in size - but now when we add a new field the whole table locks and I've left it running as long as I dare, but once its locked it holds up queries on the live site. It is also causing "Metadata locking" on other queries.

Its running on a decent server and the hosts say its just 'one of those things' in so much as its doing what (MYSQL) is designed to do.

So my idea is out of hours to create a new table with the changes to the fields, then import the data back in, but I'm not really that happy with it as a solution as it means we couldnt do any urgent development work during the day if required.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this please?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers so far guys, to answer some of the questions;

1) "Dev work on live site?" - we have a development environment, but sooner or later you need to put those changes live! Thats what I meant.

2) "Duplicating what work MYSQL does?" - from other searches on Google, it was suggested a good solution was to create an empty table, make the changes to the fields you need, then re-import the old data in (then drop the old table). Not sure if this is quicker/better than just letting MYSQL chug through creating a tmp table?

3) @Uueerdo - its a pretty basic set up, InnoDB table with keys. Its the table that holds all the completed customer cart details (we have a floating table for orders in progress) and is accessed constantly (new records being added, customer services checking orders, customers checking tracking etc). I need to add 4-5 new fields to this table and when I commit the 'ALTER' it just locks up the table and hence starts queuing the above mentioned queries that need this data.

Comment: In addition to what Bogdan Burim, another thing to speed up the update process that we do at our corp, is to make the new fields nullable when we can. It speeds up considerably on MS SQL Server.

Comment: "...as it means we couldnt do any urgent development work during the day if required." You're performing development work on a live server?!

Comment: Also, what is your current structure, and what changes are you trying to make? And how long is "as long as I dare"?

Comment: LOL `the hosts say its just 'one of those things'`. I like how they're always so super helpful =)

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch your website to maintenance mode before starting to alter big tables.
You need to shut down everything that can query the database during the alter execution.

Yes, it  is sad to have the service down, but it is best way as far as you have single DB server.

About creating separate table and migrate data their by yourself - I do not know your details, but it looks like you are going things that MySQL does itself internally, so it is usually not needed to do such things by your own.

Also, after starting the ALTER execution, you can open another MySQL connection and run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see how your query execution is going.